# Reasonable stock price information for commerical site (not alpha vantage or quandl)?

Tags: python, django, stocks, alpha-vantage

The previous threads about stock price information seems to be very old on SO and the answers there mainly seems to be alpha vantage which i cant use for my situation (I have tried it and communicated with them but they dont provide the data the way i need it, more on this below). The other answers also seemed to be mostly about only forex data, or at least that is what the vendors in the answers seem to work with now.

Is there any reasonable (below 500 USD a year) service that provides stock price information (it does not have to be real time) in addition to historic stock price information and forex to be used in python for NASDAQ, NYSE and Oslo stock exchange ? It is going to be used in a web application (django).

I used alpha vantage, but the data they return is in a series so you have to download and parse quite a bit of data when you only need one intraday value for one stock and the performance overhead for this is too much, the parsing however could be done, but it also polutes the code. Quandl was also a product I was looking at but it does not seem to provide the data i need because they dont seem to provide data for the exchanges in question and the usage seems to be needlessly complicated for some reason.

Does anyone know about a service providing this data ? Most services seem to either only offer forex data, are too expensive or does not support Oslo stock exchange.

Previously we could only use google or yahoo and it seems like some people are using their web services, but this does not seem to be allowed for commercial sites.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently subscribed to http://www.kibot.com/agent/?v=1.0.1374.0 and while I cannot attest to the validity of the data yet as I am still writing a converter to my existing format. 
I will say their most expensive package is 100 per month and includes everything I need and I am hoping to settle in with them.

This is what I signed up for;
Daily updates, API and FTP access
+ over 4 years of intraday data

This subscription includes over 4 years of daily and minute interval data (since 2014) for all Stocks, ETFs, Futures contracts, Forex pairs and full access to API and FTP. Below is the list of all the features that are included:

Best of all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for an API as Im writing a program myself to extract stock market information. From my understanding what you are linking to is access to stock information, but not information that is available through an API for programming purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Best I've found for a US stocks market data feed with a commercial license for < $500 USD per month is https://site.financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/pricing

Otherwise, these guys are what yahoo finance used to use: https://www.csidata.com/

However, they don't have an API. csidata is accessed via an FTP.